# django.db.models.query_utils.InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have given customized name to id(primary key) and used as String eg

```
custId=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10)
```

I am using raw queries to execute SQL. But Django gives me an error

```
raise InvalidQuery('Raw query must include the primary key')
django.db.models.query_utils.InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key.
```

The Query is

```
cust=Customer.objects.raw("""SELECT "custCity" FROM customer where "custId"= 'Cust101'  """)
for c in cust:
   print(c)
```

also, the table has a foreign key also showing an error.
in my transaction table, orderId is a foreign key.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "transaction" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from Transaction
```

I have searched for this but didn't get the expected answer.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, maybe the ORM needs the PK to build the Python objects, so try: `("""SELECT "custId", "custCity" FROM customer ...` adding the pk to the returned data.

Comment: hey @C14L Thanks I have solved the first issue now the second one is remaining pl help me to find out that one also.

Answer (score 0):

For first question I have solved an issue
answer is

```
>>>cust=Customer.objects.raw("""SELECT "custId" , "custCity" FROM customer where "custId"= 'Cust101'  """)

>>> for c in cust:
`...     print(c)`
```